# Make bootstrap menu slide from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

does anyone know how to make the bootstrap navigation on mobile slide from right to left, the default was slide down, i want to make something like this, but really not sure to start as i should stop first the default trigger, but don't know where the file located

reference : http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index2.html

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/os848rv1/1/

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->




<script>
$('#navbar').click(function(){

                if ($('#navbar').is(':hidden')) {

                   $('#navbar').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                } else {

                   $('#navbar').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
                 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a popular Bootstrap fork - Jasny Bootstrap. It makes bootstrap menu slide from right to left The link is: https://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/#navmenu

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at fiddle link it might help you. Let me know if its working fine with you.

http://jsfiddle.net/zzh0ym2m/6/

```
$marginLefty.animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? $marginRight.width() : 0

    })
```

Comment: Hi thanks, currently thinking, how about the submenu to do the same behaviour too @steevan , thx btw